# Point on arc using Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having an issue in getting the point on the arc. I have drawn an arc. And I want to get the point on the arc using the radius,origin and angle. In my case origin is 150,150. Radius is 50. And starting angle is 0 and ending angle is 180. When I am trying to get the point at angle M_PI/2 it should be aligned on the middle of the arc but it is giving the wrong x and y values. Please let me know if I am missing any thing.

[image]

My code is

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,
                                     [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextAddArc(context, 150, 150, 50, 0, M_PI, 0);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

}

-(CGPoint)getPoint:(float)angle
{
    float radius = 50;
    //float x = 160+radius*cos(-M_PI/2);
    //float y = 160+radius*sin(-M_PI/2);

    float x = 150+radius*cos(angle);
    float y = 150+radius*sin(angle);

    return CGPointMake(x, y);
}
```

Comment: What result do you get?  Since cos(-pi/2) = 0 and sin(-pi/2) = -1, I'd expect (x, y) = (150, 100).  Is that answer you get?  I don't like all those hard coded magic numbers.  Your method is less general.  I'd pass those in as parameters.

Comment: What I am missing is the angle passed to `getPoint` and the method you use to draw it. Also, I beleive that you should be subtracting the `radius * sin(angle)` since the y axis is inverted on iOS.

Comment: @duffymo when I pass M_PI/2 to the getPoint method I am getting 177 and 192 .Those are not correct. This is the issue

Comment: Then I'd say that value of the angle is incorrect.  Where are you getting it from, and what is the value?  Check your assumptions.  Can you step into the method using a debugger?  It'll be easy to solve if you do.

Comment: @Sulthan incorrect.  The negative sign that's required is taken care of by the sine function.  The axes, angles, and signs are correct as written.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting a point (177, 192) as you have written in the comments, that means that the angle that you passed is approximately equal to `1`. That's not `M_PI / 2`, which is approximately `1.57`.

So, the problem is in the value you are passing, not in the mentioned function. Maybe you have rounded the angle to an integer by mistake?

Comment: @TENSRI You have still not added the relevant part of the code to your question, specifically how are you calling `getPoint`.